# Why we would look at a vector with with contra-variant or covariant components?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know why we would consider looking at a vector in the two ways: by their contra-variant and covariant components. Specifically, I would like to know how they contribute to the geometry of space? While I'm here, could you also give me the reason why vectors and dual vectors are defined to have the dot product being equal to either 1 or 0?

Comment: Clear explanation:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors

Comment: Would it be possible to answer this question by starting off with the basics and build up to it? Preferably something that can answer the question like, "What was the motivation/insight into framing the conditions in such a way?" I am aware that not everything can put into simple terms, but could the rationale be explained?